# ClassCast Exception although class,package and classloaders are same while using Quartz Scheduler

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, classloader, quartz

So, I faced this issue which I wasn't even aware that could happen.
So far my understanding is JVM identifies class with a combination of class-name,package-name and the classloader name. I have verified that all of these 3 are matching and still I am getting ClassCastException.

```
@Component
public class SomeBean(){
//this is my service
}
```

I am able to successfully inject it using spring autowired in of my classes where I inject it into the Quartz Scheduler's context which looks something like:

```
scheduler.getContext().put("Key",SomeBeanInstance);
```

I am trying to fetch this bean inside my Quartz Job's execute method which roughly looks like following:

```
SomeBean someBeanInstance = (SomeBean) schedulerContext.get("key");
```

This gives me class cast exception along the lines of:
`cannot cast a.b.SomeBean to a.b.SomeBean`. I verified classLoader both at my class where someBean is injected and Quartz job and it's the same. It is `RestartClassLoader (org.spring.devtools)`

How do I fix this issue?

Is there a better way to inject service beans into a quartz job?